# copy excel cell and paste it to specific word doc

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, copy

I'm new to VBA and I need to copy one cell (that contains Data) from excel to a **specific** (not from a template) word document. the full path of the specific file will be in a cell next to the targeted cell - offset(0,1). All of that obviously in a loop because I have a big list and  a lot of files.

this is my code (the code is made of some part I picked up while searching) - but I get an

> object error

```
Sub OpenWordFile()
    Dim oWord As Object
    Dim xRg As Object
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xVal As Range
    Dim Workbook As Workbook
    Dim FileName As Variant



    'Word Object

    Set oWord = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
    oWord.Visible = True

    'Open Word Document (need to be multiple files in a loop)

    'oWord.documents.Open FileName:="C:\Users\tamirre\Desktop\New folder\135-185844.doc"      ' OPEN AN EXISTING FILE.
    'Set oWord = Nothing

    'Activating Excel to copy Cells

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select Cells to copy to word docs:", ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For Each xCell In xRg
        xVal = xCell.Value
        Set FileName = xVal.Offset(0, 1) 'Cell Must Contain name and full path of the doc file
        xVal.Copy
            oWord.documents.Open FileName:="FileName"
                Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
                Selection.TypeParagraph
                Selection.PasteExcelTable True, False, False
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: (a) You probably need to change `Selection` to `oWord.Selection`, or else it will be thinking that it is referring to Excel's `Selection` object.  (b) Unless you have a reference to the Word Object library included in your Excel project, `wdStory` will default to zero - you will need to set it to `6` (c) `xVal = xCell.Value` makes no sense if `xVal` is a `Range` object.  I suspect you just want to say `Set xVal = xCell`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: (d) Your `InputBox` is setting the `HelpContextID` to be 8.  You either need to add an extra `,` or else use `Type:=8`

Answer (score 0):

`InputBox` returns a `String`, not an `Object`.

Change the `Dim` line to this:

```
Dim xRg As String
```

and change the `InputBox` lines to this:

```
xRg = InputBox("Please select Cells to copy to word docs:", "Range Selection", ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address)
If xRg ="" Then Exit Sub
```

Then if you want to turn it into a `Range` object:

```
Dim xRange As Object
Set xRange = Range(xRg)
```

However, I do not recommend doing what you are doing this way. There are too many chances the user will enter something invalid and you will get errors.

Comment: VBA's [`InputBox` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/inputbox-function) returns a `String`, but the [`Application.InputBox` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-inputbox-method-excel) returns a `Variant` and, with the type set to 8, it returns a `Variant/Range`.

Comment: Interesting. Learn something new every day.

Comment: LOL - I just noticed that the OP doesn't have a `Type` of 8, it has a `HelpContextID` of 8.  The line seems to be missing a comma. (I had thought that that one line was one of the few that was correct!)

Comment: Gotta pay attention to those commas. ;)

Comment: Hi brax thanks for your quick help! However when I implement your corrections I still get an error this time "Method 'Range' of object _' Global' failed. [Run-time error '1004']. Any idea why? @braX